# blog post posted from blogger on facebook, image is missing

Tags: facebook, blogger

While sharing a blog post, created using blogger, noticed that text content get shared but the image is missing. Though it shows while sharing.

http://blog.instateam.net/2015/05/tips-for-sports-parents.html

I tried `<link rel="image_src" href="...` and `<meta property="og:image" content="`

Thanks

Comment: If you use the debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ it will tell you exactly what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blogger post image won't show if your blogger template doesn't contain `Open Graph Meta Tags`. You can fix this issue by adding the following code to after `<head>`tag to your template.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
  <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh! it is still not working after adding the above code.
You can try sharing using above link.

Comment: @ anurodh sahu: it works for me. see the screenshot


shared link: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-o5hzxOxMPk0/VVWfrfDjy2I/AAAAAAAABoE/HvlwHO5Zy1I/s1600/fb-share.jpg


Post Link: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-H7rtWODmrHI/VVWeF9vqkFI/AAAAAAAABn4/MUQ4HlChYOQ/s1600/fb-image.jpg